# Use OR condition in query with multiple collections MongoDb / Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, collections

I have 4 different collections.

1. Directory with data

```
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "6273678b3aff1e611a110723"
        },
        "name": "ABC Innovations",
        "address": "L.H.Road"
        "pin": {
            "$oid": "62721c1dc82651c1c61e9cf3"
        },
        "isActive": true,
    }
```

2. Pincode with below data

```
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "62721c1dc82651c1c61e9cf3"
        },
        "pin": "400001",
        "city": {
            "$oid": "627213815c18f6586d145a27"
        },
        "state": {
            "$oid": "6232c55dc24a1ae10df722f2"
        },
    }
```

3. City with below data

```
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "627213815c18f6586d145a27"
        },
        "name": "Surat",
        "state": {
            "$oid": "6232c55dc24a1ae10df722f2"
        },
    }
```

4. State with below data

```
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "6232c55dc24a1ae10df722f2"
        },
        "name": "Gujarat",
        "isActive": true
    }
```

I want to generate a query to filter out Directory list based on direcotry name, address, city name and state name with or condition.

For example,
If I search ABC or Surat or Gujarat or L.H.Road, the above Directory data should be returned.

In short I need to implement or condition in query for direcotry name, address, city name and state name

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: look like you need $lookup https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: I want to add or condition on all 4 where conditions, that's the biggest problem @jinny